Finding the Center of Broken Vase Slices
I have some slices from a broken vase and I'm trying to determine the center of each slice. Both the outer and inner edges of the slices should ideally share the same center. Can anyone suggest how I might go about finding this center for each piece?
Thank you!

The slices may not be perpendicular to the main axis of the vase, which means it could be a bit elliptical...




If this was 2D, you could take tangents at various points, so the lines at right-angles to the tangent should pass through the centre of the circle.  For a 3D vase, ideally you would want the tangents to be planes and the lines at right angles would pass through the axis of rotational symmetry.  But this would not work so simply with 2D images of 3D pieces.
